Battery disconnect switch when battery voltage is higher than external supply
I have a device that can be powered from USB but also from primary batteries. Battery voltage is higher than USB voltage. When USB is connected I want to drain as little as possible from the batteries. Of course I also want the circuit to draw as little extra current as possible when running from the batteries. Short power loss when disconnecting USB is acceptable.
I have come up with this idea:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Later I came also up with this idea:

simulate this circuit
In the second circuit T1 gate will be at most at -0.7 V when closed so there might be some tiny leakage through the transistor in USB mode. There should be virtually on leakage in battery mode.
The penalty of both circuits is the battery current through 2M2 (or some higher value).
Is there a better/smarter/cheaper topology? My main constrain is device cost.

Optocouplers are expensive. Just use two jellybean transistors, an NPN and a PNP.

Is battery voltage ALWAYS higher than USB voltage? Even when battery is low on charge?

Battery voltage (2x Li-SOCl2) is always higher than USB. Batteries will go down to 6.0 V before being replaced.

The new circuit will work too, but I would add two resistors.  You shouldn't leave the T3 gate floating (which it would be when VUSB is gone) so you should put a pulldown resistor there.  You should add a resistor in between base of T2 and drain of T3, otherwise you'll dump a bunch of wasted current through that path.


Battery voltage (2x Li-SOCl2) is always higher than USB. Batteries
will go down to 6.0 V before being replaced.

If this is indeed true then you don't have to worry about reverse current through the P-channel MOSFET, simplifying the solution.  Your circuit will work fine, but the optocoupler seems a bit overkill for what you're trying to do and you mention that cost is a big factor.  All you need instead are two cheap N-channel MOSFETs, like shown below.  2N7002-style MOSFETs can come in dual packages and can be quite cheap.

D1 (just like in your own circuit) is there to prevent M2 from turning on when the battery path is engaged.  It also prevents battery power backfeeding into the USB power source for the short amount of time it takes between when USB power is connected and for all the cascaded MOSFETs to switch states.  You need to size D1 for its current rating based on how much your buck converter pulls.  You didn't mention any details on that, so I just picked a jellybean BAT54 schottky diode as a placeholder.  The value of R1 is going to determine how much extra power is wasted from the battery when USB power is connected.  R2 is going to determine how much extra power is wasted from the battery when USB power is disconnected.  R3 is less critical, but for simplicity I used the same value you had for all three of them.
If you want to simulate the circuit yourself in LTspice, copy/paste the following text into a file with a .asc file extension and open it in the program.  You can delete Vusb and re-run the simulation to see what happens when USB power is disconnected.
Version 4
SHEET 1 1896 840
WIRE -80 96 -256 96
WIRE 64 96 -80 96
WIRE 160 96 64 96
WIRE 336 96 256 96
WIRE 64 128 64 96
WIRE -256 144 -256 96
WIRE -80 176 -80 96
WIRE 64 224 64 208
WIRE 176 224 176 144
WIRE 176 224 64 224
WIRE 176 240 176 224
WIRE -256 272 -256 224
WIRE -80 320 -80 256
WIRE 128 320 -80 320
WIRE -80 352 -80 320
WIRE 336 352 336 96
WIRE 528 352 336 352
WIRE 176 368 176 336
WIRE 528 384 528 352
WIRE -192 432 -256 432
WIRE -128 432 -192 432
WIRE -192 448 -192 432
WIRE 528 512 528 464
WIRE -192 544 -192 528
WIRE -80 544 -80 448
WIRE -80 544 -192 544
WIRE -80 576 -80 544
WIRE -256 608 -256 432
WIRE 144 608 -256 608
WIRE 336 608 336 352
WIRE 336 608 208 608
WIRE -256 672 -256 608
WIRE -256 800 -256 752
FLAG -256 272 0
FLAG -256 800 0
FLAG 528 512 0
FLAG 176 368 0
FLAG -80 576 0
DATAFLAG 448 352 ""
SYMBOL pmos 256 144 M270
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value DMP4065SQ
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMBOL Misc\\battery -256 128 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vbat
SYMATTR Value 7.2
SYMBOL nmos -128 352 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value 2N7002
SYMBOL res -96 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 2.2Meg
SYMBOL nmos 128 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value 2N7002
SYMBOL res 48 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 2.2Meg
SYMBOL res -208 432 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 2.2Meg
SYMBOL schottky 144 624 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value BAT54
SYMATTR Description Diode
SYMATTR Type diode
SYMBOL voltage -256 656 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vusb
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL current 528 384 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 108 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName I1
SYMATTR Value 100m
SYMATTR SpiceLine load
TEXT 728 104 Left 2 !*---------- DMP4065SQ Spice Model ----------\n.SUBCKT DMP4065SQ 10 20 30 \n*     TERMINALS:  D  G  S\nM1 1 2 3 3 PMOS L = 1E-006 W = 1E-006 \nRD 10 1 0.04289 \nRS 30 3 0.001 \nRG 20 2 10.24 \nCGS 2 3 5.75E-010 \nEGD 12 30 2 1 1 \nVFB 14 30 0 \nFFB 2 1 VFB 1 \nCGD 13 14 4.5E-010 \nR1 13 30 1 \nD1 13 12 DLIM \nDDG 14 15 DCGD \nR2 12 15 1 \nD2 30 15 DLIM \nDSD 10 3 DSUB \n.MODEL PMOS PMOS LEVEL = 3 U0 = 400 VMAX = 1E+006 ETA = 0.001 \n+ TOX = 6E-008 NSUB = 1E+016 KP = 8.015 KAPPA = 19.32 VTO = -1.585 \n.MODEL DCGD D CJO = 1.7E-010 VJ = 0.8 M = 0.6 \n.MODEL DSUB D IS = 2.364E-010 N = 1.26 RS = 0.0254 BV = 46 CJO = 2.226E-010 VJ = 0.8 M = 0.6 \n.MODEL DLIM D IS = 0.0001 \n.ENDS\n*Diodes DMP4065SQ Spice Model v1.0M Last Revised 2017/9/19
TEXT -26 752 Left 2 !.op


I think I don't understand?
Vusb present = M2 open = M1 gate grounded = M1 open = battery drain ?
Vusb absent = M2 closed = M1 gate pulled up = M1 closed = no power ?

@filo You’re totally right to be confused. I got the logic backwards. Doh! My bad. I’ll try to salvage the answer or write a different one if I can’t.

@filo  OK, I was able to rework the answer.  Let me know if this makes more sense now, or if it's still completely illogical.
